# Why do I need to use subsitution method for this integral?

Tags: integration

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \int \frac{x^3}{x-1}\text{d}x$.

Why can't I solve it directly using power formula i.e. $\displaystyle \int x^n\text{d}x=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$?

Comment: You need to perform long division first and then the integration will be straight forward.

Comment: @John, I think that substitution will be easier in this case (u=x-1). OP, if you don't want to use substitution you can write $x^3=x^3-1+1$ and then split the integrals into two separate integrals (which is the same as John's method).

Comment: How would you use the power formula ? Please show us.

Comment: In simplier words, power formula requires an integrand in form of  $x^n$, where integration is performed with respect to variable $x$. Substitution often helps one to change the main variable into a new one (say, $u$), while rewriting the integrand in to the form of $u^m$, thus power formula can be applied.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int \frac{x^3}{x-1}dx= \int \left(x^2+x + \frac{1}{x-1}\right)dx = ?$$

The reason you can't apply the power formula straight away is because it is not of the form $x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Another way to see where is the problem.*

Let $x=y+1$; the integrand becomes $$\frac{x^3}{x-1}=\frac{(y+1)^3}{y}=\frac{y^3+3y^2+3y+1}{y}=y^2+3y+3+\frac 1y$$ You can apply $$\displaystyle \int y^n\text{d}y=\frac{y^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ for any $n$ **except** for $n=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it any way you like, but still have to deal with the fact that $\frac{x^3}{x-1}$ is not a polynomial, due to the singularity at $x=1$. Writing $x^3$ as $(x^3-1)+1$ leads to
$$ \frac{x^3}{x-1}=\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x-1}=1+x+x^2+\frac{1}{x-1} $$
hence a primitive is given by $x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\log(x-1)$, where the logarithmic term appears as a consequence of the previous singularity (simple pole at $x=1$).